# Use XSLT to enumerate Nodes with the same name

Tags: xslt, muenchian-grouping

I have many many XML files that often contain nodes mutiple times (each time with different data).
Example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <SomeName>  
      <Node>
        DataA
     </Node>  
     <Node>
        DataB
     </Node>  
      <Node>
        DataC
     </Node>  
      <AnotherNode>
        DataD
     </AnotherNode>
      <AnotherNode>
        DataE
     </AnotherNode>
      <AnotherNode>
        DataF
     </AnotherNode>
     <SingleNode>
        DataG
     </SingleNode>
   </SomeName>
```

The desired Output would be:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <SomeName>  
      <Node1>
        DataA
     </Node1>  
     <Node2>
        DataB
     </Node2>  
      <Node3>
        DataC
     </Node3>  
      <AnotherNode1>
        DataD
     </AnotherNode1>
      <AnotherNode2>
        DataE
     </AnotherNode2>
      <AnotherNode3>
        DataF
     </AnotherNode3>
     <SingleNode>
        DataG
     </SingleNode>
   </SomeName>
```

The Problem is, I don't have a list of all the duplicate Nodenames, so I need the XSLT to run through all nodes and only number those that exist multiple times. Is that possible?

Does anyone have a good idea on how to accomplish that?

Thanks!

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete and more efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a complete solution**. **It is recommended** to use the Muenchian method for grouping and not grouping based on `count(preceding::*[someCondition])`, which is grossly inefficient -- O(N^2).

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kElsByName"
  match="/*/*" use="name()"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <SomeName>
     <xsl:for-each select=
      "*[generate-id()
        =
         generate-id(key('kElsByName', name())[1])
        ]
      ">

        <xsl:variable name="vsameNamedNodes" select=
         "key('kElsByName', name())"/>

        <xsl:variable name="vNumSameNamedNodes" select=
         "count($vsameNamedNodes)"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="$vsameNamedNodes">

         <xsl:element name="{concat(name(),
                             substring(position(),
                                       1 div ($vNumSameNamedNodes > 1)
                                       )
                                    )
                             }">
           <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
         </xsl:element>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </SomeName>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
    <SomeName>
      <Node>
        DataA
     </Node>
     <Node>
        DataB
     </Node>
      <Node>
        DataC
     </Node>
      <AnotherNode>
        DataD
     </AnotherNode>
      <AnotherNode>
        DataE
     </AnotherNode>
      <AnotherNode>
        DataF
     </AnotherNode>
     <SingleNode>
        DataG
     </SingleNode>
   </SomeName>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<SomeName>
    <Node1>
        DataA
    </Node1>
    <Node2>
        DataB
    </Node2>
    <Node3>
        DataC
    </Node3>
    <AnotherNode1>
        DataD
    </AnotherNode1>
    <AnotherNode2>
        DataE
    </AnotherNode2>
    <AnotherNode3>
        DataF
    </AnotherNode3>
    <SingleNode>
        DataG
    </SingleNode>
</SomeName>
```

Comment: Wow. That worked beautifully and quickly too! Thanks a lot for that XSLT! All I changed was putting  method="xml" into the header to have XML outputs, but otherwise your solution is perfect.
Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, is there a possibility to change that to not rename unique nodes? Basically have the XSLT not rename the SingleNode?
Thanks!

Comment: @Grinner: yes, but it is inconvenient to write the new solution into a comment. I may edit my answer to include this last requirement.

Comment: @Grinner: I edited my answer. The solution now produces exactly the output you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count(preceding-sibling::*[name(.) = name(current())])` to get the number of preceding sibling elements with the same name as the context element, and `<xsl:element name="concat(name(.),'n')" />` to create an element of the same name as the context element, with the letter 'n' appended to it.  Combining these facts should allow you to achieve the effect you desire.

Comment: Using `count(preceding-sibling::*[something])` is quite inefficient (O(N^2)). See my answer for a more efficient solution.